Teaching Beginners
I have a friend who is in his nineties with some memory loss and he wants to learn the harmonica and the ukulele. I play the harmonica a little and I've been trained in music for years. He needs to learn fundamentals first, I think, like what the note names are (A, B, C, D, etc) and what types of notes there are, and so on. Can anyone advise how should I best approach this?

Vtc, as this kind of question is out of bounds for this site. However, please don't bamboozle the poor student with theory and note names - they just want to play, so teaching a few basics with no theory attached is way better.

You're kind of on your own here; every student is different, and every 90-yr-old even more so. I doubt there's any reference tailored to "elderly people with slight memory loss," and if there were it would say only "see what works for this individual by trial and error." Music can have a unique immunity to memory loss (see the work of Oliver Sachs, esp Musicophilia), so you might find that they can memorize tunes and fingerings even if they can't learn note or chord names.

Also, to elaborate on Tim's comment: Requests for outside resources aren't on-topic here. But you can easily edit the question from "recommend a book" to simply "how should I best approach this."

@Tim he is not a "poor student", he is courageous one. no pity.

@turanarican - 'poor' could also mean he has little money! But here, maybe the term is more UK orientated, meaning potentially poorly treated. Lost in translation, unless your comment was a joke.

He doesn't need a rigorous musical education, he just wants to PLAY the things!   Teach him chord names and shapes on ukulele, he'll probably need to follow a chord sheet.   Maybe he'll want to read music for the harmonica, but I'd start with just showing him how to play it!

+1 for just playing, not bogging things down with theory.  I"m sure he'll let you know if he is dying to learn his key signatures...

Also, ahead of time can you find out what kind of music he likes?  With this knowledge in hand, you can try to pre-select a song or two that you know will be easy to learn on ukulele

I know he likes bluegrass and jazz. I wasn't really thinking about teaching key signatures to him, but this guy didn't even know what the note names on a staff were. How can I explain chords to him if he didn't even know what the notes in the chord are? For example, if I told him: "This is a C7 chord" he didn't even know what a C was.

@rickyfan3956 well, for ukulele at least stick with tab to begin with, most beginner uke or guitar players of any age will be playing songs before they know the notes in a C major chord or have seen one written down as sheet music. Especially when sheet music for guitar can be a little tricky and ambiguous with all the repeated notes! I really don’t think you need to start with note names on a staff, a shape of a chord and a name is sufficient for getting most people going, then introduce that the lowest note in that chord is where the name comes from etc.. notation tends to come later..

"How can I explain chords to him if he didn't even know what the notes in the chord are?"    You don't have to EXPLAIN chords, just show him the shapes.

I actually don't play the ukulele, so I can't show him the shapes. I do, however, play the harmonica somewhat as well as the flute, the recorder, and the piano and I sing.

@rickyfan3956 - you don't actually play uke? How would one go about teaching that in this situation..?

"I actually don't play the ukulele" !!!!!  Guess you'll have to 'learn as you teach' then!

Initially, I wasn't really planning on teaching him the ukulele, just some music fundamentals and a bit of the harmonica. However, I have been interested for a while in learning the ukulele myself, so now I'm a beginning learner on the ukulele as well. Both my husband (who plays SEVERAL different stringed instruments) and I have decided to learn the ukulele together.

@rickyfan3956 Uke is a pretty accommodating instrument. Many elementary school programs have replaced the de-rigeur recorder curriculum with ukuleles, being just about as cheap to acquire, and a bit more soothing in tone. I'm confident you could learn four chords in half an hour on youtube. But the fact remains, any instrument could be taught in practical rather than theoretical terms. For recorder, it would be "put these fingers on these holes." Letter names just make the communication easier, so teach them along the way as needed.

@Andy Bonner, I agree about the uke. With as many chords as I've learned in the two days I've been practicing and already being able to chord along to simple songs, I'm quite encouraged. We drove in headfirst and bought three ukes, my husband and I, and we're learning the uke together. Of course, he says he doesn't have as big a learning curve as I have because he's been playing guitar for 20 years, whereas I've been primarily a wind player. Incidentally, my friend has expressed an interest in learning about note values as well as note names, and I will teach him, but.. baby steps, baby steps.

@rickyfan3956 I'd offer a more nuanced take on Laurence's answer here, then: For any beginning student, I think it's best to learn the conceptual framework of music "by doing." I.e. not "This is the staff. This line is G. Play it like this," but "Play this. Oh by the way that's a G. Oh by the way this is how it's written" (with all that spread out over days or weeks of scaffolding each bit of practical experience before "explaining" it with theory). And there are many good beginning method books for many instruments that do that, or you can even make your own materials.

@AndyBonner For a further nuance, my answer was aimed at a mature student 'with some memory loss'.   More generally, we needn't be afraid of throwing it all at a student at once!  'This is C.  Here it is on the instrument, here it is on the page.'   People are cleverer than we give them credit for when working out these pedagogical schemes.

@Andy Bonner, I think that is, esseni, what I'm going to do. And that is, essentially, how I'm learning the uke myself.
